# Hiking routes near Embrun

Tags: france, hiking, maps, alps

We arrived in Embrun few days ago and surprisingly we can't find any map of hiking routes. We are surrounded by Alps and we don't know where to start climbing from, what are the expected times of a climb etc. Neither OpenTopoMap nor Google Maps help.

I am surprised because in all the mountains I've been previously it was super easy to find such a map (i.e. Polish Tatry Mountains near Zakopane, Sudety, Swedish/Norwegian mountains) and Alps are one of the most popular tourist destination in France/Europe.

What am I missing and where can I find such a map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard maps for hiking in France is the series [TOP25](https://ignrando.fr/boutique/cartes/randonnee-france.html?ign_serie=1217) (scale 1:25000) of the national mapping agency [Institut National de l’Information Géographique et Forestière (IGN)](http://www.ign.fr). You can find those in all the logical places. The maps of the Embrun region will be in stock and for sale in tourist offices in and near Embrun, decent bookstores near Embrun and travel bookstores in France and neighbouring countries.

Like many modern mapping agencies, the IGN has an [online viewer](https://www.geoportail.gouv.fr/carte) where you can look at the maps online. Just zoom to Embrun (or type Embrun in the search box on top of that page), click on "Cartes" in the upper left corner and select under "Fonds de Cartes" either "Carte topographique IGN" or "Cartes IGN classiques" and you have a nice hiking map of the region.
[image: Screenshot of the geoportail]